# how to convert the time type of 2020-06-02 10:40:28.001 to 1591065628 in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

how to convert the time type of 2020-06-02 10:40:28.001 to 1591065628 in TDengine database?
I want to convert the time in a certain format and can see it in the shell. Take an example, I want to convert the time 2020-06-02 10:40:28.001 to 1591065628, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use taos -r option, it will output time as uint64_t

```sql
ubuntu@taos ~ $ taos -r

taos> use test;
Database changed.

taos> select * from tb;
       ts       |   speed    |            desc             |
================================================================
 1644216894189 |           1 | test                        |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.006103s)
```